# Cloudformation Route Erroring Out

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm creating a public route to my internet gateway. When I configure this through the GUI, it's no problem at all. When I try to do it through my Cloudformation template, it fails every time. Here is the construction of the Gateway, which doesn't have any issues:

```
GatewayToInternet:
  Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  DependsOn: VPC
  Properties:
    Tags:
    - Key: Name
      Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-IGW
  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref GatewayToInternet
```

Here is the route I'm attaching that is causing issues:

```
PublicDefaultRoute1
  Type: AWS::EC2::Route
  DependsOn: GatewayToInternet
  Properties:
    RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
    GatewayId: !Ref GatewayToInternet
    DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
```

The error I get from the CLI is: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 261, column 5)

If I remove the route, everything works perfectly. I don't have any other routes attached to that Route Table, if that matters.

Comment: Can you confirm that your template doesn't have invalid YAML syntax using a YAML validator? Edit: never mind, I found the issue

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
PublicDefaultRoute1
  Type: AWS::EC2::Route
  DependsOn: GatewayToInternet
  Properties:
    RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
    GatewayId: !Ref GatewayToInternet
    DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
```

should be

```yaml
PublicDefaultRoute1:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Route
  DependsOn: GatewayToInternet
  Properties:
    RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
    GatewayId: !Ref GatewayToInternet
    DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Note the colon (:) in PublicDefaultRoute1